# How to add delay in Google Places API request?

Tags: java, android

I want to reduce request to Google Places API by adding delay for every user input but i am not sure how to implement this. This is what i usually do to add delay to my EditText waiting for user's input:

```
        editTextEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            isEmailValid = false;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
            enableDisableButton();
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callGooglePlacesAPI()
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    });
```

This is my code to call Google PLaces API:

```
    editTextLocation.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editTextLocation.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
            searchLocation();
        }
        }
    });


public void searchLocation(){
    try
    {
        editTextLocation.clearFocus();
        //hide soft keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                .build(getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Please help give advice on this. Thank you.

Comment: Is the Handler not working?

Comment: It is working fine. But i just know how to implement this in EditText. I am not sure how to implement this to autocomplete. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, `callGooglePlacesAPI()` will need to update some list that's displayed as part of the autocomplete list